# All my blocks has deleted

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, blocks

I have a private network for testing. My problem is when ever I stop running geth network, all of my mined blocks are gone. I run like

```
geth --datadir "ethereum/node1" --port 30301 --networkid 1234 --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --ws --wsport "8546" --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

(sometimes I use nohup) and I stop the server using cntrl+c. When geth is running I check block number using `eth.blockNumber` and it will show block number and it will increment. After I stop and start my server then I check using eth.blockNumber it always shows 0 and it takes some hour to mine blocks. Due to this, I'm lossing many of test data. Is this a common problem? Is there any work around to prevent this? Any idea will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I'd enable logs adding `-verbosity 5` to geth command line. If geth finishes cleanly it should restart where it left. From your description it appears geth has some problem closing that might leave the database with invalid data that forces a restart from block 0.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `geth export <filename>` and `geth import <filename>`

[from Go Ethereum Wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore)

Answer (score 1):

> sometimes I use nohup

What do you see when you tail the logs?

> tail -f nohup.out

I suspect geth is just trying to determine current state corresponding to the highest block in your local node and shows block 0 until that is done.